# What is happening to my houseplants all of a sudden?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health

My plants were doing fine, in fact great. But now all of a sudden, they are all dying. The leaves are drooping and getting brown and black. few examples:

[image]

[image]

The temp soared to 45c degree here but they were kept in bright indirect light and with a huge tub full of water near the plants for humidity. I have no idea what happened to the plants all of a sudden. Song of Indian, Rubber plant, Monstera, Arrowhead vine, Poinsettia, dumbcane and all. What could be wrong here? I checked roots of some plants, and they are no signs of root rot.

My watering technique is same as before.

EDIT: More pics

[image]
[image]

Funny thing is that my Lemon Lime dracaena is super fine and growing along with Croton plant. But all other plants are dying.

Comment: What was your watering regime? The plants might need more water during a heatwave namely.

Comment: @benn i watered them whenever half an inch topsoil got dry. I sometimes I watered twice because the soil mix would get dry in the afternoon. I watered each according to their needs. Was very careful with watering.

Comment: It might be the heat, was it ever so hot before? 45C?

Comment: @benn yeah. last year also it was so hot, but they were just fine.

Comment: If your light, temperature, and watering is all good my last guess is fertilizers. If that's also something you'd rule out, I don't know sorry.

Comment: @benn I am more inclined to blame the heat caused by my window AC. Heatwave + heat from AC outlet could be the problem? My plants on terrace are doing fine. I would rule the fertilizers out.

Comment: I wouldn't advise to put your plants it in the hot AC outlet, I missed that in your description...